# ssh tunnel, port forwarding - confused

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh-tunneling, port-forwarding

Can someone explain what this command is doing ?

```
ssh -L5000:localhost:5000 user1@somedomain.com -t ssh -L5000:localhost:22 tec02
```

Answer (score 4):

> ssh -L5000:localhost:5000 user1@somedomain.com -t

this part make connection and forward local port 5000 to port 5000 on remote hhost

> ssh -L5000:localhost:22 tec02

this part run on  ssh
which connect to  as same user (user1) and forward local (from point of view somedomain.com) port 5000 to port 22 on host tec02

As result of this double forwards, after it You can connect by ssh to local port 5000 and get connected to tec02 (for sftp for example)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

To understand lets break the command into 2 parts

```
ssh -L5000:localhost:5000 user1@somedomain.com
```

and

```
L5000:localhost:22 tec02
```

> First commands does - bind port 5000 of my machine to port 5000 ( of
>   localhost ) using the machine somedomain.com

This binds the port 5000 of your machine using the ssh to the port 5000 of a remote machine. It is using somedomain.com to connect to localhost or anything that could be communicable with somedomain.com, in this case somedomain.com can communicate with its localhost so through ssh a connection is established to localhost of somedomain.com

> and secondly, in the second part of the command. The port 5000 of
>   somedomain.com ( which is now bind with the port 5000 of our machine)
>   is bind to port 22 of tec02 by the same process

NOTE: The user on tec02 is also user1.

say 
something like this

ssh -L5000:localhost:5000 user1@somedomain.com -t ssh -L5000:localhost:22 user1@tec02

Answer (score 0):

For easily remembering REMOTE always pairs with LOCAL and vice versa LOCAL - REMOTE. Parse the command from left to right **-L** as abbrev for **LOCAL** and **-R** as abbrev for **REMOTE**.

I want: on **(R)EMOTE** port 2000 **POINT TO** my **LOCAL**'s localhost port 22 with my remote's host is `mypublicremotehost.com`.

**`ssh -R2000:localhost:22 mypublicremotehost.com`**

I want: on **(L)OCAL** port 2345 **POINT TO** my **REMOTE**'s localhost port 8080 with my remote's host is `mypublicremotehost.com`.

**`ssh -L2345:localhost:8080 mypublicremotehost.com`**